# Meteor HTTP call is different from jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, meteor

I have the same call in Meteor HTTP and in jQuery ajax. But the response from server is different.

Meteor:

```
HTTP.call("POST", url, {
    params: data
}, function (error, result) {
  //My works....
})
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  "url": url,
  "method": "POST",
  "data": data,
  success: function(data_res) {
    //My works...
  }
})
```

I would expect the same result, but jquery is executed correctly, while meteor returns an error.

Are calls not identical?

Comment: Use the `network` tab in your dev tools, and compare both requests. Find out their differences

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor method call, Use 'data' field instead of 'params' as it's a POST request.
Try this in Meteor :

```
HTTP.post( URL, {data:dataToBePosted,headers:{key:value}}//if headers needed use headers field 
   ,function( error, response ) {

   if ( error ) {
      console.log( error );
   } else {
      console.log( response);
   }
});
```